# form validation in codeigniter with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, codeigniter, validation

I want to validate groupname.

I am using ajax but it is not working

This is my view

```
<?php echo form_input(['name'=>'groupname','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter group name','value'=>'','ng-model'=>'myWelcome[0].groupname','onkeyup'=>'loadValid(this.value)']) ?>
```

Javascript function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function loadValid(v) {
     if(v)
     {
         var url= window.location.href;
         var res = url.split("/");
         var groupid = res[res.length-1];
         var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
             }
          };
         xhttp.open("GET", site_url + "admin/Usergroup_controller/store_edit_group_name_ajax/" + groupid + "/" + v, true);
         xhttp.send();
     }
     else
     {
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Group name is required field.";
     }
  }
</script>
```

Controller function

```
public function store_edit_group_name_ajax($groupid,$groupname)
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('groupname', 'Group name', 'trim|required|alpha|is_unique[group.groupname]|min_length[3]');

    if( $this->form_validation->run() )
    {
        echo form_error('groupname','<p class="text-danger">','</p>');
    }
}
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are creating a response object first.

```
$response = new stdClass();
if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
    $response->status = 'failure';
    $response->error = validation_errors('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');
}
...
return $response;
```

In Javascript after getting response;

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText.error;
```

Just echo-ing ajax results is something you need to leave immediately. Please take it as a friendly advise.